# Can a windows driver access the page table of a process?

Tags: windows, driver, virtual-memory

In Windows, a kernel driver can do things like pinning memory to back up a virtual address range (`MMProbeandLockPages`). But I could not find a way to actually verify that a virtual address is valid for a specific process. In other words, is there any way for a kernel driver to check whether a given virtual page is contained in the page table of a given process?

Answer (score 0):

If the driver is not running in the process' context you have to call KeStackAttachProcess first.

Then, you can do ProbeForRead or ProbForWrite inside try / except block. For example, see handling of IOCTL_SIOCTL_METHOD_NEITHER in src\general\ioctl\wdm\sys\sioctl.c in WinDDK samples.

Comment: I assume the driver will need to keep in mind that the address might be valid at the time it is probed but become invalid afterwards, potentially immediately?

Comment: Harry Johnston: true. Any read or write should be in the same try/except block and the IRQL should be PASSIVE.